# Destroy Object on Keyboard button press

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am Making a game like fire-fighter, i have a scenario that, machine is on fire due to electricity, first player have to switch off electricity, so i made button and show that  press o to turn off electricity but i am unable to destroy electricity object, here is my code i do so far, but nothing goes good.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class SwitchONOFF : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform Player;
public Texture texture;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}
// Update is called once per frame
void OnGUI () {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, transform.position);

    if(distance<2 )
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (600, 150, 200, 100), texture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, false);
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.O)) {
            Destroy (gameObject.tag="chin");// here i want to destroy object with a tag of "chin", but how
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already doing this wrong by using `OnGUI` and also searching `GameObject` to destroy by `tag` instead of caching the GameObject in the `Start` function. To get your current code to work, simply replace `Destroy (gameObject.tag="chin");` with

`Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("chin"));`

or

`Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("chin"));`

Comment: It is fixed :-) @Programmer THANKS ALOT

Comment: @FarhanAli You are welcome. You should accept it as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah I tried to accept it, but it says after 7 mins so I wait :-)

Comment: @FarhanAli Ahh I see. Didn't even know there is a time limit on this. Anyways, you need to stop using OnGUI. It is old and slow. Use the new UI https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsZM3q74Q2k

Comment: i am unable to post another question due to time limit so can i have your time just for some more mins i need one more favor from you.

Comment: I am always here. Just link the question here once your time limit is gone. I will answer if I know the answer or comment if I don't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080244/rotate-object-through-script-on-instantiate-object

Kindly visit this question